# qiskit qaoa.compute_minimum_eigenvalue

Tags: qiskit, programming, qaoa

I am having some trouble running the `compute_minimum_eigenvalue` method from qiskit's  `QAOA`: [the documentation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.algorithms.QAOA.compute_minimum_eigenvalue.html#qiskit.algorithms.QAOA.compute_minimum_eigenvalue) states that one need to pass `H` (" *Qubit operator of the Observable*" as `OperatorBase`).
My question is, given that I implemented `H` as `QuantumCircuit`, how can I convert it to the right format?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can create a quantum_info/Operator from the QuantumCircuit and with that operator create an opflow/MatrixOp, you can try that. There is a more direct route using opflow/CircuitOp but I think the former is more likely to work. Normally the operator there is a pauli sum from a higher level application, but the above will convert it to the right type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had suggested in my comment above how you might do this. `Operator` is not an opflow `OperatorBase` (it's a `BaseOperator` - different type) but can be used to create an opflow `MatrixOp` which is. Given your code sample above, I did the following based on it, which runs and prints values.

```
import numpy as np
from qiskit import BasicAer, QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.algorithms import QAOA
from qiskit.algorithms.optimizers import COBYLA
from qiskit.quantum_info.operators import Operator
from qiskit.opflow import MatrixOp

nqubits = 4
H = QuantumCircuit(nqubits)
for i in range(nqubits):
    H.z(i)
    H_op = MatrixOp(Operator(H))
    qaoa = QAOA(optimizer= COBYLA(), reps=1, mixer=H,
                initial_point=np.array([1.0]),
                quantum_instance=BasicAer.get_backend('statevector_simulator'))
    print(qaoa.compute_minimum_eigenvalue(H_op))
```

*Note*: you should use an `optimizer` from the `qiskit.algorithms.optimizers` package - the `qiskit.optimization` is part of the now *deprecated and unsupported* `Qiskit Aqua`, and that specific module you had used (CobylaOptimizer), in any case, had a different purpose.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have an additional question: when I want to see the circuit I do `qaoa.construct_circuit([1.], H_op)[0].draw()`, and I have noticed something odd: there is a block that contains all 4 qubits that says "Hamiltonian". Do you know what it is and what it does? Because from what I could understand until now, there is an additional parameter that goes into this Hamiltonian, but I don't see why it should be there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I'm interpreting the scope of the question correctly, but you can convert a `QuantumCircuit` to a compatible `OperatorBase` type for `compute_minimum_eigenvalue` as follows:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.algorithms import QAOA
from qiskit.opflow import MatrixOp
from qiskit.quantum_info.operators import Operator

circuit = QuantumCircuit(1)
circuit.h(0)

op = MatrixOp(Operator(circuit)) # convert circuit to operator

qaoa = QAOA(...) # specifications of your problem

qaoa.compute_minimum_eigenvalue(op, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But if I try to run this with a simple QAOA I get a strange error: `qiskit.exceptions.QiskitError: 'other is not a number'`. My code is: 
`from qiskit.algorithms import QAOA
from qiskit.optimization.algorithms import CobylaOptimizer
from qiskit.quantum_info.operators import Operator
nqubits = 4
H = QuantumCircuit(nqubits)
for i in range(nqubits):
    H.z(i)

H_op = Operator(H)

qaoa = QAOA(optimizer= CobylaOptimizer,reps=1,mixer=H,initial_point=np.array([1.0, 1.0]),quantum_instance=quantum_instance)
print(qaoa.compute_minimum_eigenvalue(H_op))`

Comment: Gotcha I see that now, take a look at Steve Wood's answer that seemed to fix it https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/26519/13991